# angular material flex on header is not working

Tags: css, angular-material

I have an issue on CSS with the header (mat-toolbar). I try put "A" on the left side and "B" on the right side.

What is working:

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <mat-toolbar-row>
  A
   <span class="flex-spacer"></span>
  B
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container class="prometheus-sidenav-container">
...
</mat-sidenav-container>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

[image]

I tryed now to move now A and B in a component as header.

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <mat-toolbar-row>
  <app-header></app-header>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container class="prometheus-sidenav-container">
...
</mat-sidenav-container>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

the header template:

```
A
<span class="flex-spacer"></span>
B
```

The header looks like following picture:

[image]

in style.scss

```
.flex-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

some idea way flex is not working here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move  inside the a component two things happen

- The parent is now no longer mat-toolbar-row and has the display rule value as block
- flex-spacer CSS is in your component style, so it will not update any other components that have the flex-spacer class

To solve the problem

- Move .flex-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  } to styles.css
- And in the parent component CSS add these rules
  app-header {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  }